# MySQL Delete Row That Is Older Than The Current Date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete events in my database that have a start date older than the current day.

I've used the NOW statement and it deleted all of the content within my table.

The database is updated daily with events and I want to delete the events that have passed.

Here is a sample of my sql statement:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Detroit WHERE Detroit.startDate < CURDATE()");
```

startDate is the name of the column in the db where all of the date information is stored.

The dates appear as Fri, 25 Apr 2014 19:00:00.  When I use the CURDATE or NOW date options within my statement, the whole table is deleted. How do I delete the rows with the dates older than the current date?

Comment: so what error you are getting ?

Comment: Can you add to your question please. What is the data type of the `startDate` column in your table. Also what is the issue with the query you have given as an example

Comment: You have a table called detroit? The mind boggles.

Comment: Do `Delete from Detroit where DATE(Detroit.startDate) < CURDATE()`

Comment: Suketu thank you but this did not delete anything from the table.

Comment: Abhik I am not getting an error but when I used the now statement and the curdate statement it deleted the contents of the table.

Comment: Riggs the data type for startDate appears as Fri, 25 Apr 2014 19:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your `startDate` column is not a datetime field, but it's a varchar instead.

This query should work:

```
DELETE FROM Detroit
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(startDate, '%a, %e %b %Y') < CURDATE()
```

Or you could try to substitute %e with %d. However, it is always a better idea to use a DATETIME column and not a VARCHAR column to store date and times, so you should create a new column startDatedt and update your table this way:

```
UPDATE Detroit
SET startDatedt = STR_TO_DATE(startDate, '%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%S')
```

and then you could just use date and time functions to delete the rows that you need:

```
DELETE FROM Detroit WHERE startDatedt < CURDATE()
```

Please have a look here to see [how to compose a date format string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: fthiella you were dead on.  I realized the column was a varchar column and used your second option to create a new column and changed it to timestamp and this worked flawlessly.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with the UNIX Timestamp(Seconds after the 1st january 1970, this format is always in UTC), you can use this code:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Detroit WHERE Detroit.startDate < ".time());
```

Let me know if you're using another format and I make another code snippet.

Comment: I see it. Thanks for saying it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know its result please:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Detroit WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),startDate) > 0");
```

Comment: There was no error message.  You can run it from here and it does not provide any message:  http://nightlyplus.com/revamp/inc/cronjobcommand.php

Comment: May I have your skype account ?!